# Are these users bots or people?

Tags: discord

I have a question about discord bots (well kind of). Recently people have been joining my server (the majority have dots in their user). Most of the time when they join, I am offline. They will send a message in about 5 channels in the server that say “my naked pictures” and with a hook up link. A lot of people in the server believe they are bots and I think that some of them are but I also believe some are not. Sometimes I’ll be online when they join and I’ll warn them “No naked pictures” or “Children under the age of 13 in the server” something like that. The ones I have had the chance to warn, didn’t send the links or any messages. They’ve just stayed in the sever until an admin banned them. The other thing is that I’ve read some things where it is not a bot unless it had the bold letters next to it that read “BOT”. None of the users have the “BOT” next to their user. So I’m very confused. Is this happening to anybody else and if it is, are they bots or people??

Comment: I'm not sure that this is the forum for this sort of question but I'll give a response none the less. There is no explicit way for you to tell if they are bot or actual users. Account with `Bot` next to their names are created as bot accounts. Normal user accounts can still be automated (referred to as `user bots`) and they will **not** have the `Bot` tag by their names. Usually a server raid or this type of behavior is carried out by Bots, but can include actual users with alt accounts as well. Note: actual bot accounts cannot join your server without someone adding it manually. User bots can

Comment: Thank you Anu6is.

Answer (score 0):

Bots are identified by a blue "Bot" tag next (not in) their username. Note that, as mentioned in the comments, a bot can run off a user's account, which won't have the bot tag. These are called userbots, and are against Discord's terms of service to operate. So yes, in your case those were bots running off of user accounts.